# Where to source security ID data (ISIN, CUSIP)?

Tags: market-data, database

I am lookign for a list of ISINs or CUSIP for all equity securities traded on the NASDAQ and NYSE.

while not quantitative, this question is directly related to the data collection process of many quant finance studies so I apologize in advance if this is not the appropriate place to ask.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been sorted. I'll post here for anyone else looking:

I downloaded the Tickers in excel format from the NAz website:

http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ

Using the Bloomberg terminal in uni and the excel API i have the ticker list in column A and i input the following in column B:

```
=BDP(A2&" US Equity","ID_ISIN")
```

the output is the ISIN for the ticker in A2.

Cheers.